# Rcpp Power Set implementation : attempt to set index 8/8 in SET_VECTOR_ELT

Tags: r, rcpp

**Consider the function which takes a set of elements as an input vector and returns the power set in a list:**

```
> pwr_set(letters[1:3])

[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "a"

[[3]]
[1] "b"

[[4]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[5]]
[1] "c"

[[6]]
[1] "a" "c"

[[7]]
[1] "b" "c"

[[8]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

**R definition:**

```
pwr_set <- function(els){
  n_els <- length(els)
  out <- vector(mode="list",length = 2 ^ n_els)
  out[[1]] <- character()     # first element in power set is the empty set

  listIdx <- 1L       # start a listIdx

  for(i in 1L:n_els){
    for(j in 1L:listIdx){
      listIdx <- listIdx + 1L
      out[[listIdx]] <- c(out[[j]], els[i])
    }
  }
  out
}
```

#### I have come up with the following translation to implement in Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
List pwr_set_cpp(CharacterVector els) {

  int n_els = els.size();         // size of set
  int pwrset_card = pow(2,n_els); // number of subsets to make power set is 2^n_elements
  List out(pwrset_card);          // list for output
  int listidx = 0;                // to count through list indeces
  out[0] = CharacterVector::create(); // first element of list represents empty set
  CharacterVector tmp;            // to hold new extended vector

  for (int i=0; i < n_els; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j <= listidx; ++j) {

      listidx++;
      tmp = out[j];
      tmp.push_back(els[i]);
      out[listidx] = tmp;

    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

#### But!

```
> pwr_set_cpp(letters[1:3])
```

gives me the error: **`attempt to set index 8/8 in SET_VECTOR_ELT`**

Googling and looking at the source code [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/barrier_8cpp_source.html) leads me to think that I am trying to index beyond what `SET_VECTOR_ELT` has cached? This must mean I mis-understand how to step through input/output loops in `Rcpp` or something of the sort.

*Any guidance in helping me understand here would be wonderful.* Thanks ahead of time.

## UPDATE: the fix.

As per answer/comments by @Romain Francois and @nicola the key misunderstanding was that way that you step through loops in `R` is sorta clever! (or at least I now appreciate it more than before). To implement the same thing in `c++` I have to break up the `listidx` into a `counter` variable (which is the condition check for `j`) and an interim `cnt2` which essentially records the number of `j` steps taken *on top of* the current counter state. `counter` then gets updated after passing each exit with the current value of `cnt2`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List pwr_set_cpp(CharacterVector els) {

  int n_els = els.size();         
  int pwrset_card = pow(2,n_els); 
  List out(pwrset_card);          
  out[0] = StringVector::create(); 
  CharacterVector tmp;            
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < n_els; ++i) {
    int cnt2 = counter;            // capture counter state
      for (int j =0; j <= counter; ++j) {
        cnt2++;                   // capture counter + j steps
        tmp = as<StringVector>(out[j]);
        tmp.push_back(as<std::string>(els[i]));
        out[cnt2] = tmp;

    }
      counter = cnt2;             // update counter state
  }
  return out;
}
```

### quick timings

Just for fun a little benchmark. Although I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this (with the same algorithm structure) as I'm doing a lot of copying of `STRSXP` elements/vectors.

```
x <- letters[1:18]
pwr_set_bitecompile <- compiler::cmpfun(pwr_set) # R 3.2.0 !
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    pwr_set(x),
    pwr_set_bitecompile(x),
    pwr_set_cpp(x))

Unit: milliseconds
                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
             pwr_set(x) 748.6553 820.0667 841.2828 834.1229 856.2436 1023.1324   100
 pwr_set_bitecompile(x) 365.9969 480.9474 498.2100 503.5115 518.8562  596.8205   100
         pwr_set_cpp(x) 155.9447 283.8771 295.8411 300.4865 314.0826  342.0261   100
```

Comment: Use `for (int j=0; j < listidx; ++j)` and then continue debugging.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how can the `j` loop possibly come to a end? You increase `listidx` every time inside the loop and it seems that the condition `j<listidx` is always met, if  met the first time. Keep in mind that R and C/C++ handle loops very differently.

Comment: @nicola this is precisely where I was confused you are very correct! I've updated my question describing how I fixed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to assign something into `out[8]` and that's above the number of elements in the list.

See with this added line:

```
  Rprintf( "out.size() = %d, listidx = %d\n", out.size(), listidx );
  out[listidx] = tmp;
```

You'll get:

```
> pwr_set_cpp(letters[1:3])
out.size() = 8, listidx = 1
out.size() = 8, listidx = 2
out.size() = 8, listidx = 3
out.size() = 8, listidx = 4
out.size() = 8, listidx = 5
out.size() = 8, listidx = 6
out.size() = 8, listidx = 7
out.size() = 8, listidx = 8
Error in pwr_set_cpp(letters[1:3]) :
  tentative de modification de l'index 8/8 dans SET_VECTOR_ELT
Calls: sourceCpp ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> pwr_set_cpp -> <Anonymous>
Exécution arrêtée
```

See also the comment from @nicola. You're doing something wrong with `listidx` and `j`. If the overflow did not stop it, you'd get an endless loop.

What's probably confusing is that the R code:

```
for(j in 1L:listIdx){
  listIdx <- listIdx + 1L
  out[[listIdx]] <- c(out[[j]], els[i])
}
```

evaluates `1L:listIdx` once, so that inside the loop, you can use `listIdx` to do something else. That's not the case in C++.

Comment: The confusing bit to me was precisely that thanks! I've updated my question with the implementation that works given this. Is there a way (given the same algorithm idea) to code this another way(s) in C++? Just hints or pointers to resources is plenty!